# If $X \simeq Y$, then for every $p \in X$ there exists a $q\in Y$ such that $\pi_1(X,p) \simeq \pi_1(Y,q)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

**Question:**

Show that if $X, Y$ have the same homotopy type, then for every $p \in X$ there exists a $q \in Y$ such that $$\pi_1(X,p) \simeq \pi_1(Y,q)$$

**Solution attempt**

From what I understand, I need to show that I for $X \simeq Y$. I can always find two points such that $(X,p) \simeq_* (Y,q)$. Since $\pi_1$ is a homotopic functor, then it would be all there is to show.

$X \simeq Y$ implies there exists $f:X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ two continuous maps such that
$$g \circ f \simeq id_X$$
$$f \circ g \simeq id_Y$$

What I would like to have is that $f(p) = q$.

I am not really sure what is going on from now since $f(p)$ is equal to some point $q\in Y$ even if it is pointed or not so am I missing some important point?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: hi Ianatore. it seems to me this question is not about homotopy type theory, so I have replaced that tag with the `homotopy-theory` tag; I hope that's alright

Comment: regarding your question, the easiest way to prove it is as follows. let $f:X\leftrightarrows Y:g$ be the homotopy equivalences. given $p\in X$, let $q=f(p)$; you wish to show that $\pi_1(X,p)\cong\pi_1(Y,q)$. note that $f$ induces a map $\pi_1(X,p)\to\pi_1(Y,q)$; unfortunately, we do not necessarily have $g(q)=p$, so $g$ does not necessarily induce a map in the other direction.  ...

Comment: ... what you should show is that $g(q)$ lies in the same path component of $X$ as $p$, and then exploit this fact to modify the natural map $\pi_1(Y,q)\to\pi_1(X,g(q))$ induced by $g$ into a map $\pi_1(Y,q)\to\pi_1(X,p)$.

Comment: if you do this carefully, you will then be able to show that the two maps $\pi_1(X,p)\leftrightarrows \pi_1(Y,q)$ are mutually inverse, which will show the desired result.

Comment: Do you know about the fundamental groupoid $\Pi(X)$? If yes, then you can use that a homotopy equivalence $f\colon X\to Y$ induces an equivalence of groupoids, and equivalences of categories are fully faithful.

Answer (score 1):

The complete argument can be found in Theorem 7.40 of the book "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by Lee. He shows that homotopic equivalence implies that the fundamental groups are isomorphic with an auxiliary lemma. I'm sure he does it that way for some reason, so, instead of trying to compactify what Lee does in this answer, I'd rather give you the reference so you can check it out calmly.